# IOException parsing XML document from class path resource

Tags: java, xml, spring, classpath

Ok I'm currently trying `mavenise` a project. However my project fails to find the `xml` file containing the some beans. `combined2.xml`

I have it defined as:

```
    public RepeatingGrpPoC() {
    appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            new String[] { "src/main/java/resources/combined2.xml",});
    c = 0;    
}
```

However for a reason unknown to me I constantly get the error.

> Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [src/main/java/resources/combined2.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [src/main/java/resources/combined2.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:212)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:126)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:92)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:465)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:395)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
>       at metadataPoC.RepeatingGrpPoC.(RepeatingGrpPoC.java:34)
>       at metadataPoC.Main.main(Main.java:22)
>   Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [src/main/java/resources/combined2.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
>       at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:141)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328)
>       ... 14 more

Where else would the program be looking for this file since I've given it the relative path?

Comment: isn't it usually of this pattern `"src/main/resources/combined2.xml"` ?

Comment: Please see my answer at : https://stackoverflow.com/a/66230703/5916535

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It is trying to load this file from the classpath and cannot find it. Try specifying just `"combined2.xml"` instead of `"src/main/java/resources/combined2.xml"` and make sure that src/main/java/resources is on your classpath.

By the way, in Maven, the standard directory for resources is `src/main/resources`, so I suggest you put this file there.

Comment: sir I am getting the same error but I am using java project instead of maven.

Answer (score 9):

Maven, has standard directory for resources. Which is `src/main/resources`, so if you keep your file here it will take it.

**For example**

```
 ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml");
```

I had the same problem it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace your .xml in resources folder, and write:

```
 String[] contextPaths = new String[] {"Xxx.xml"};
    new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(contextPaths);
```

If you didn't any addition configuration, all .html and .xml files Spring searches in resources folder by dafault

Answer (score 1):

Keep `.xml` files in the resources folder and use `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` like this:

Example:

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
```

Answer (score 1):

**2023/4**

if the classpath for resources is ok but still annoys,
at a very least this works in Eclipse

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:combined2.xml");
```

(refer to
[Spring docs->Core](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html) paragraph **ClassPathResource** in
**Resources-> Built-in Resource Implementations**)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            new String[] { "/**/combined2.xml", "/**/xxx.xml"});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the relative path of the xml file.
Relative path: path relative to your package where the XML file is located.

E.g. 
assume

```
package = beanfactory,  
xml file name = application-context.xml,
```

and xml file in under this package.
then provide the path as "/beanfactory/application-context.xml"

```
ApplicationContext factory=new 
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/beanfactory/application-context.xml");
```

This works without errors.

Answer (score 0):

Move `combined2.xml` to your `resources` folder.

If you want to put any other config file like `applicationContext.xml`, make sure you put it in `resources` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are multiple solution for it, your choose whichever you want to implement in your project.

```
#1stStep
1) Move "combined2.xml" file to [src/main/resource]. 
2) Use *ApplicationContext context = new ApplicationContext(parent 
   class,args);*
```

*The [parent class] value is actually the main java class file or the current class where you are facing this issue.

```
#2ndStep
If you still wanna use your method, then consider following the solution 
below:-
1) Move "combined2.xml" file to [src/main/java]
2) Use *ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new 
   ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("combined2.xml");*
```

Elaboration of #2ndStep:-
You put the xml file under wrong folder [src/main/java/resources], your "combined.xml" file should be under [src/main/java]. You don't have to give full directory of the path for an example: "src/main/java/resources/combined2.xml", just put the name of the [.xml] file you have created. Based on your project, you created "**combined2.xml**", just pass the name of the file which is "**combined2.xml**". The exact solution was given below based on your project structure.

Exact Solution:-

```
public RepeatingGrpPoC() {
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext appContext = new 
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("combined2.xml");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Put the Config file under Resource folder if you are using Maven. Like below.

[image]

Answer (score -3):

I got it..
correct answer

```
ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            new String[] { "/**/applicationContext.xml", "/**/xxx.xml"});
```

Comment: Dr Subhash Mohandas , the purpose of this post is to say thanks for the several existing answers which basically propose the same solution, isn't it? If you intend to contribute additional insight please make that more obvious by [edit]ing to explain the relevant difference.