# I can't run my first Spring application, Hello World? I have added all the jars

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, jar

I am having problem trying to run my first spring application that displays Hello world at my console. I am getting this error.

```
Oct 16, 2013 10:24:37 AM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@5d764be1: startup date [Wed Oct 16 10:24:37 EAT 2013]; root of context hierarchy
Oct 16, 2013 10:24:37 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [Beans.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [Beans.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [Beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:243)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:527)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:441)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at come.tutorialspoint.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:10)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [Beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:157)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328)
    ... 13 more
```

here is the Beans.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-
3.0.xsd">
<bean id="helloWorld" class="com.tutorialspoint.HelloWorld">
<property name="message" value="Hello World!"/>
 </bean>
</beans>
```

I have create the Beans.xml file in the exact package by right clicking and adding android .xml file. 
 Here is the java class:

```
package come.tutorialspoint;

public class HelloWorld {
   private String message;

   public void setMessage(String message){
      this.message  = message;
   }

   public void getMessage(){
      System.out.println("Your Message : " + message);
   }
}
```

Here is the Main class:

```
public class MainApp {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");
    HelloWorld obj = (HelloWorld) context.getBean("helloWorld");
    obj.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well it's failing to find Beans.xml... so do you have that file, and where is it?

Comment: Please attach here the code that starts the application context and your project structure (the folders and where each file resides)

Comment: @JonSkeet I have the Beans.xml file at my package. I will post the exact code.

Comment: @Avi I have attached the code

Comment: @link - Please publish the project structure - the folders you have and where does each file reside.

Comment: @Avi I don't understand, 'project structure', do you mean my workspace and project files or the place i put my jar files?

Comment: Your source code resides in folders.
For example - something like `src/main/java/com/mycompany/utils/HelloWorld.java` (for a file `HelloWorld.java` in package `com.mycompany.utils`)
I need to understand where your `beans.xml` is in your projects structure.

Comment: The reason I'm asking for it is because you're getting a `FileNotFoundException` which means that your `beans.xml` file is not in the root of your class path (which is where you're trying to load it from), it somewhere else and I need to understand where.

Comment: Ok, The java class  /Springfirst/src/come/tutorialspoint/HelloWorld.java, the .xml: /Springfirst/src/come/tutorialspoint/Beans.xml the main app class : /Springfirst/src/come/tutorialspoint/MainApp.java The Springfirst being the project name and tutorialspoint is the package name

Comment: /home/aaaa/Documents/workspace.aaaa/Springfirst/src/come/tutorialspoint/MainApp.java,     /home/aaaa/Documents/workspace.aaaa/Springfirst/src/come/tutorialspoint/Beans.xml   /home/aaaa/Documents/workspace.aaaa/Springfirst/src/come/tutorialspoint/HelloWorld.java @Avi

Comment: Try to have a look at [this stackoverflow topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893760/spring-cannot-find-bean-xml-configuration-file-when-it-does-exist).

Maybe it will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Based on one of your last comments to the question, your **Beans.xml is in the wrong location**. Options:

- Move Beans.xml to "src/main/resources/Beans.xml"

or

- Move Beans.xml to "src/main/java/Beans.xml"

or

- Change `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml")` to `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("come/tutorialspoint/Beans.xml")`;

The first option is the preferred option per Java/Maven conventions.

Your error is that [ClassPathXmlApplicationContext](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/context/support/ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.html) expects a classpath location, and that includes any package information. Your Beans.xml is currently sitting in the package "come.tutorialspoint";

For more info:

- [Spring 3 Documentation - Application contexts and Resource paths](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch05s07.html)
- [Spring cannot find bean xml configuration file when it does exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893760/spring-cannot-find-bean-xml-configuration-file-when-it-does-exist)

Comment: Just noticed I answered a question that's almost eight months old since last activity. Not sure why it was in the recent questions feed.

Answer (score 0):

Keep you Bean.xml in same package of your Java files and instead Of using:

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml")
```

Use:

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("come/tutorialspoint/Beans.xml");
```