# Can not open beans.xml (config file) because does not exist

Tags: java, xml, spring, javabeans

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   IOException parsing XML document from class path resource
>   [com/main/beans.xml]; nested exception is
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
>   [com/main/beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

```
ApplicationContext context = 
      new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("com/main/beans.xml");
```

I have tried before with

```
ApplicationContext context = 
     new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("src/main/java/com/main/beans.xml");
```

And it works well.

How to do that relative to the classpath?

**Note:** classpath is in the build path

---

In the example I'm following, it has the following structure and it works

**Project structure**

[image: Project structure]

**Classpath**

[image: Classpath]

```
ApplicationContext context = 
    new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("com/caveofprogramming/spring/test/beans/beans.xml");
```

Comment: xml files should be in `src/main/resources` not in java. When compiling with maven the xml files are ignored if they aren't in resources (Unless you do some extra work to add them back).

Comment: see my **UPDATE** below

Comment: @M.Deinum thank you -- useful! But why it worked in the example? Seems that author didn't do some extra work

Comment: It might work from within eclipse (as that sucks at computing the classpath especially with Maven projects), when building the jar/war it won't be in that location.

Comment: Keep you beans.xml in classpath or src/main/...pkg where java file are saved. And then use ClassPathXmlApplicationCOntext

Comment: Please see my answer at : https://stackoverflow.com/a/66230703/5916535. Hope it helps

Answer (score 6):

Here's the file structure I normally use, which works fine. As @M.Deinum said, you'll want to put your xml file in a `src/main/resources`. I normally put to the it in a complete package path with the resources so during compile time, maven will add all the resources to same path as the corresponding classes that use them.

[image]

resources get copied to the class package when you do the above

[image]

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context
                = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("com/underdogdevs/stackmaven/beans.xml");

        Hello hello = (Hello) context.getBean("hello");
        hello.sayHello();
    }
}
```

Works fine for me. If you're wondering why you still need to use the complete package name when the xml is already in the same class packages, its it will first be searched for in the class root

---

**UPDATE**

put the package with the `bean.xml` into the `src/main/resources`. It should work with the path your using.

---

**UPDATE 2**

> "Yes, it worked. But why is it working the example, I'm following as well. If the beans.xml is out of src/main/resources .. I can't find out how that works? *

The thing is, the Spring container will look from the class root. It has nothing to with the `resources` folder. The `resources` is a convenience dir for maven projects to build to your class path. The reason the tutorial works, is that the `beans.xml` is in a **package**, that will get put into the class path in the build, as seen below. It is only *preferred* to use a `resources`, but a package` will also build to the class path.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Yes, it worked. But why is it working the example, I'm following as well. If the beans.xml is out of src/main/resources  http://173.248.174.172/~caveofpr/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/spring-tutorial-8.zip
I can't find out how that works?

Comment: See my **UPDATE** 2. Hope that clarifies things.

Comment: Yes, clear me up this. I also say that in Build path I had *.java instead of all, that the example had.

Comment: Now I tried to run but it come up with another problem, eclipse now tell me that 'Selection does not have main type'. 
Is my eclipse proyect corrupt?

Comment: See [**here**](https://www.google.com/search?q=Selection%20does%20not%20have%20main%20type%27). It could be a couple different things. Also make sure the class with your `main` method is the Main Class. You can do to your run config to see that.