# How do I solve " java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [Beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist " this error?

Tags: java, spring

My question is about this error message:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [Beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

How do I solve it?

[image]

In the image we can spot an error in the console window and also can see the main method program.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please go through these two pages - 
[How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring cannot find bean xml configuration file when it does exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893760/spring-cannot-find-bean-xml-configuration-file-when-it-does-exist)

Comment: Have you checked this?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893760/spring-cannot-find-bean-xml-configuration-file-when-it-does-exist

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of exception, check you have created an XML file in the src folder directly, not in the package where your main class is present. I solved this program by the same method.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the issue by

1. `beans.xml` file in com.tuto package so move to src  folder
2. specify the `com.tuto.Beans.xml` in `ApplicationContext`